# How to put osgEarth's ViewerWidget into an tabbed MdiArea?

Tags: c++, qt, openscenegraph

Is there something special about putting osgEarth's `ViewerViewer` into a `QMdiArea`? I created a `QMdiArea` as central Widget (called `setCentralWidget`) instead of taking `osgEarth`'s viewer directly as central widget.

```
QMdiArea *mdiArea = new QMdiArea(this); 
setCentralWidget(mdiArea); // call to QMainWindows method, snippet is taken from app's MainWindow 
mdiArea->addSubWindow(viewerWidget); // this doesn't work, globe is not drawn
```

Everything I tried didn't worked... except osgEarth's `ViewerWidget` is set as central widget of my `MainWindow`. Also tried `MultiViewerWidget` without any success but because I need only one view the `ViewerWidget` should be ok, or not?

I had a look into the examples but didn't succed to use one of them as starting point.

Any hints? Thank's in advance.

Comment: osgEearth uses OpenGL right? If I remember correctly QMdiArea has some issues with OpenGL widgets. Don't take my word for it though as I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the subwindow's geometry before starting the UI.

```
   QMdiSubWindow* sw = mdiArea->addSubWindow(viewerWidget); 
   sw->setGeometry(...);
```

Otherwise OSG will probably become confused.

Got this answer by Gwaldron in the osgEarth forum [here](http://forum.osgearth.org/osgEarthViewer-in-Qt-s-MdiArea-td7582039.html) and it worked.

Also setting a minimum size for the viewerWidget will help (e.g. for positioning on TabWidget). See my question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828411/osgviewer-in-qts-tabwidget).

Comment: Hello Thomas, I am new in osgearth and qt. I want create a qt app and show osgearth view in main window, but I cant! my problem is integration between qt window and osgearth window. can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, where `Form1` is a `QDialog`

in main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Form1 w=new Form1();//qdialog
    .................//do something to initial the map
    w.loadWidget(viewerWidget);
    w.show();//the order of the loadwiget() and show() is important!!!!!
    a.exec(); 
}
```

in Form1.cpp

```
void Form1::loadWidget(QWidget *qwidget)
{
    qwidget->setMinimumSize( ui.mdiArea->width(),ui.mdiArea->height());
    QMdiSubWindow * subW=ui.mdiArea->addSubWindow(qwidget);
    subW->setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    subW->maximumSize();
}
```

This works well with `qt 4.8.4+osgearth 2.3`