# OSGViewer in Qt's TabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, openscenegraph, qtabwidget

I am using OpenSceneGraph 3.0.1 and having a problem with the Qt integration using the

`osgQt::GLWidget` when adding it to a tab control during startup (inside the constructor of my main window.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    :  QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QWidget* viewerWidget = new MyViewerWidget(new osgViewer::Viewer());

    ui->tabWidget->addTab(viewerWidget, "My Osg View");

    // tab entry was added but nothing to see than empty Osg Window
}
```

It works, when calling the code from a menu after displaying the main window:

```
void gcdrp::MainWindow::on_actionCreate_Simulation_View_triggered()
{
    QWidget* viewerWidget = new MyViewerWidget(new osgViewer::Viewer());

    ui->tabWidget->addTab(viewerWidget, "My Osg View");

    // tab with content is visible (as expected)
}
```

It seems like the scene graph is screwed up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with setMinimumSize:

```
QWidget* viewerWidget = new MyViewerWidget(new osgViewer::Viewer());

viewerWidget->setMinimumSize( ui->tabWidget->width(), ui->tabWidget->height());
```